# Best way to run tests in Truffle for contracts that rely on mainnet dependencies?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

I could create mocks of the dependencies but I'd really like to be able to fork mainnet using Ganache in a way similar to this (https://medium.com/@samajammin/how-to-interact-with-ethereums-mainnet-in-a-development-environment-with-ganache-3d8649df0876) ...but within the `truffle test` environment

Comment: So you want to deploy your contracts locally on Ganache, but then have them interacting with other contracts which are already deployed on mainnet (I suppose, either by passing those mainnet addresses to the local contracts, or by hard-coding them inside the local contracts)?

Comment: let me simplify it...i'm using a DEX as a dependency in my contract. I would like to use truffle to test against the actual contract, instead of against a mock. Is this possible?

Comment: "i'm using a DEX as a dependency in my contract" - what does that mean? Please show some relevant code.

Comment: All I'm saying is that within one of my function calls, the contract calls Uniswap, for example, and relies on that exchange succeeding, for the function to work

Comment: It's gonna be hard (or even impossible) with Truffle. Unless of course you deploy your contract into mainnet as well. Mocking is the correct way for doing it - you mock a contract with the exact same DEX function prototype, but which does nothing but returning true or false (to your request of course). Then you set this function to return `true`, then you check your contract's behavior on Ganache, then you do the same with `false`.